# python: extracting files based on partial title with split criteria in title

Tags: python, split, text-extraction

I have a list of files with inconsistent nomenclature:

```
pLst = ['CO_002_2016_Q4_Merge.loc', 'CO_002_2016_Merge.zip', 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.loc', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_alias.loc.xml', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc', 'AuburnAliasGCS_1984_1106.lox', 'CA_ORG_BCP.loc.xml', 'CA_ORG_BCP.loc', 'Co52 Alias Address Locator.lox', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc.xml', 'CentralCostaCountyStreets.lox', 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.lox']
```

I want to extract files that contain the strings in this list:

```
exCrt = ["2016_Q4", "2016_q4","2017"]
```

I would like to add all of the files with any of the elements in exCrt to an extraction list but I don't see a way to isolate the split criteria from part of the selection criteria (i.e. "_").

I tried using any:

```
if any(x in pLst for x in exCrt):
    exLst.add(x)
```

which resulted in an empty set.

I also tried changing exCrt to `["2016","q4","Q4","2017"]` and then using an 'and' 'or' approach:

```
for i in pLst:
    if exCrt[0] and exCrt[1] or exLst[0] and exCrt[2] or exCrt[3] in i.split("_"):
        exLst.add(i)
```

But this did not exclude any of the files the unwanted files.

I would like the output to be

```
( 'CO_002_2016_Q4_Composite.loc',
 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.loc.xml',
 'CO_002_2016_Q4_Composite.loc.xml',
 'CO_002_2016_Q4_Merge.lox',
 'CO_002_2016_Q4_Merge.loc.xml',
 'CO_002_2016_Q4_Merge.loc',
 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.loc',
 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.lox',
 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_alias.lox',
 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_alias.loc',
 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_alias.loc.xml',
 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc',
 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc.xml')
```

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: Im a little confused but is: `[x for x in pLst if "2016_Q4" in x or "2016_q4" in x or "2017" in x]` what you are looking for ?

Comment: @coder. That did it. I'll read up on list comprehension as I see myself using this a lot in the upcoming months. Thx!

Comment: @ShaunO you're welcome! yes list comprehension is a must for a python programmer to know!

Comment: @coder Are you going to post an answer?

Comment: @ShaunO I posted an answer! Actually is the one I posted in my upper comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple list comprehension could be used like so:

```
exLst = [i for i in pLst for j in exCrt if j in i]
```

this should work!

Answer (score 2):

Your approach using `any` will work, if you adjust as follows:

```
exCrt = ["2016_Q4", "2016_q4", "2017"]
exLst = []
for p in pLst:
    if any(x in p for x in exCrt):
        exLst.append(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension:

```
pLst = ['CO_002_2016_Q4_Merge.loc', 'CO_002_2016_Merge.zip', 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.loc', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_alias.loc.xml', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc', 'AuburnAliasGCS_1984_1106.lox', 'CA_ORG_BCP.loc.xml', 'CA_ORG_BCP.loc', 'Co52 Alias Address Locator.lox', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc.xml', 'CentralCostaCountyStreets.lox', 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.lox']

exCrt = ["2016_Q4", "2016_q4", "2017"]
final_pLst = [i for i in pLst if any(b in i for b in exCrt)]
```

Output:

```
['CO_002_2016_Q4_Merge.loc', 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.loc', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_alias.loc.xml', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc', 'CO_002_2017_here_2017_q1_streets_parity.loc.xml', 'CO_002_2016_q4_alias.lox']
```